# SharedPreference doesn't contain anything inside Broadcast Receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

So I'm new to android and I have developed a simple alarm clock app. Problem is that my alarms resets when I reboot my phone, so I created a receiver which starts at boot. This receiver is supposed to get my list of quickAlarms from my shared preference, loop through it and then send them to my AlarmService. The problem is that I am unable to get hold of the sharedPreference.
I have tried these methods:

```
    sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("my_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This is the broadcastReceiver called upon boot:

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("BootReceiver", "BootReceiver called");
    sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    //sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("my_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(sharedPref.contains("alarm")){
        Log.d("BootReceiver", "SharedPreference do contain alarms, trying to set them...");
        alarmService= new AlarmService(context);
        activate(context);
    }else{
        Log.d("BootReceiver", "SharedPreference does not contain any alarms.");
        //I always get this message, so sharedPref never contains anything here!
    }
}

/**
 * Loops through the stored list of QuickAlarms, checks if the are set to on and then reshedules them.
 * @param context
 */

public void activate(Context context) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<QuickAlarm>>() {}.getType();
    List<QuickAlarm> alarmList = gson.fromJson(sharedPref.getString("alarm", ""), type);
    Iterator<QuickAlarm> alarmIterator = alarmList.iterator();

    while(alarmIterator.hasNext()){
        if(alarmIterator.next().isActive()){
            alarmService.onHandleIntent(new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class).putExtra("time", alarmIterator.next().getTime()).setAction("CREATE").putExtra("repeat", alarmIterator.next().getRepeat()).putExtra("id" , alarmIterator.next().getID()).putExtra("desc", alarmIterator.next().getDesc()));
        }
    }
    Log.d("BootReceiver", "All alarms are set again!");
}}
```

Here is the code in MainActivity were I declare the sharedpreference and use it in the Controller class:

```
    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
//...
sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    controller = new Controller(sharedPref, this.getApplicationContext());
```

Then it's really the Controller which use it:

```
 public Controller(SharedPreferences sharedPref, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.sharedPref = sharedPref;
    editor = sharedPref.edit();
}

//...
    public void addQuickAlarm(QuickAlarm qa, int id) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<QuickAlarm>>() {
    }.getType();
    List<QuickAlarm> alarms;
    if (gson.fromJson(sharedPref.getString("alarm", ""), type) == null) {
        alarms = new ArrayList<>();
    } else {
        alarms = gson.fromJson(sharedPref.getString("alarm", ""), type);
    }
    if (id == -10) {
        alarms.add(qa);
        Log.d("Controller", "QuickAlarm added to pref");
    } else {
        alarms.remove(id);
        alarms.add(id, qa);
        Log.d("Controller", "QuickAlarm edited to pref");
    }
    String jsonAlarm = gson.toJson(alarms); //converting list to json and saving back
    editor.putString("alarm", jsonAlarm);
    editor.commit();
}
public void activateAlarm(boolean on, int id) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<QuickAlarm>>() {
    }.getType();
    List<QuickAlarm> alarmList = gson.fromJson(sharedPref.getString("alarm", ""), type);
    QuickAlarm qa = alarmList.get(id);
    qa.setActive(on);
    int[] repeat = qa.getRepeat();
    addQuickAlarm(qa, id);
    if (on) {
        alarmService.onHandleIntent(new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class).putExtra("time", qa.getTime()).setAction("CREATE").putExtra("repeat", repeat).putExtra("id" , id).putExtra("desc", qa.getDesc()));
    } else {
        alarmService.onHandleIntent(new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class).putExtra("time", qa.getTime()).setAction("CANCEL").putExtra("id" , id));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can access SharedPrefences, that is not the issue. Where do you store values in prefs?

Comment: I store them from my mainActivity. my sharedPreference only contains a list<QuickAlarm> which key is "alarm". Look at my edited post.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the "alarm" key and its value to your sharedpreference when you are setting the alarm alert something like this

```
sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("my_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

or

```
sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPref.edit();
 editor.putString("alarm", "value u want to keep");
editor.commit();
```

Comment: If I reboot my phone and start the app, my MainActivity can use the above method just fine to load all my Alarms again into my ListView. But the Alarms set with the AlarmManager is gone, so these need to be scheduled again without even opening the app.

Comment: If your problem is just setting once again the AlarmManager once the device is rebooted, you will need to add receiver for RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED and onReceive just set your alarms once again

Comment: This is what I have done. As already stated, the receiver works and is run when the phone is rebooted. The problem is that when it access my old alarms it can't find them.

Comment: can you post the code where you are calling this  sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("my_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
or
sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); at the time of setting the alarm

Comment: sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext()); every where in your activity also don't mix the call of shardpref,

Comment: sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext()); in broadcastreciever class ,also don't mix the call of shardpref,change this line sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE); to sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()); in your activity classes

Comment: This seems to have done the trick! Thank you! Now I get the list as expected in the broadcastReceiver. Now I get a new error though right after one iteration in the StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver:
Unable to start receiver com.example.user.alarmclock.Local.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: at what line of java it is coming can you post the error and code

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it, it was beacuse I used Next on the iterator. So now it should work, except nothing happends in my AlarmService, it never shedules the alarms. I call it just like I do in my Controller, but nothing happends.

Answer (score 1):

Unable to start receiver `com.example.user.alarmclock.Local.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver: java.util.NoSuchElementException` because after `alarmIterator.next().isActive()`  this you are calling another `next()` like this `alarmIterator.next().getTime()` which mean you are asking for `List<QuickAlarm >` next item object(`QuickAlarm` ) which is not there so only you are getting the error. change your code to this because even you mean `if` in this object(`QuickAlarm` )  `isActive()`  is true then pull other info from this object(`QuickAlarm` ) like `getTime()`,`getRepeat()` etc.

```
while(alarmIterator.hasNext()){
    QuickAlarm qm=alarmIterator.next()
            if(qm.isActive()){
                alarmService.onHandleIntent(new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class).putExtra("time", qm.getTime()).setAction("CREATE").putExtra("repeat", qm.getRepeat()).putExtra("id" , qm.getID()).putExtra("desc", qm.getDesc()));
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Ah, yes I figured it out. :) Now it works, my alarms get resheduled after reboot. Except one thing, they ring about 1 minut later when they should. This is another question though. Thanks!